# Redis Cache implementation - c#

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis

I am writing `redis` cache code. I have wrote for `Set` and `Get` cache. 
But how to update cache entries automatically when database/storage entries changed. How to check for whether database/storage entries changed or not.

Code snippet:

For set:
`cacheDBContext.Cache.SetObject(key, oList);`

For get:
`cacheDBContext.Cache.GetObject<T>(key);`

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Azure SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

When you update value of a key, just delete the key from the cache(redis) and update the value in your db.

When you query the value of a key, first look it up from cache, if it exists, just return. If not, query from db , then save to cache(redis) and return.

This is a simple and efficient way to keep the cache's data consistent with db's data.

Comment: Yes we can do like this. But Is there any automated way for that?
Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Ashish Mayekar no. At least I think no. It need code to maintain this.